# How can I kill the buffer when I exit emacs client

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I am using `emacsclient` to connect to an emacs server.

When I exit my `emacsclient`, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> just like how I normally exit emacs.

How can I kill the buffer on the emacs server?

I find that the emacs server still keeps the buffer and the memory usage keeps growing as I have more `emacsclient` but exit from them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: I believe it's `Ctrl-x #`.

Comment: `C-x #` runs the command server-edit — `Switch to next server editing buffer; say "Done" for current buffer.
If a server buffer is current, it is marked "done" and optionally saved.
The buffer is also killed if it did not exist before the clients asked for it.
When all of a client's buffers are marked as "done", the client is notified.` — That's interesting, and complicated also.

Answer (score 0):

Killing buffers and quitting your emacs frame are totally independant as you mention : the server keeps everything you don't close open, independently of what you display in how many windows. (I often have the same buffers open on 2 or 3 of my virtual desktops, for example not at the same point.)

To kill a buffer, that's <kbd>C-x k</kbd>.